# Custom Metadata/Settings/Labels for Configuring a Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-metadata

### Goal

I'm looking to build a mechanism to allow system administrators to easily configure various components of a **Visualforce page that is used in a site** (without having to modify code). I would like to enable them to configure the:

- Button labels
- Text that will appear on the page (rich text)
- Banner and logo images
- Field set that will appear on the page
- Page background color (in hex format)
- Hyperlink URL for a button

It seems to me that either a **custom metadata type**, or a **Visualforce tab**, or a **Lightning App Page + LWC** would be best for this purpose.

### Question

1. What would be the best way to enable admins to easily configure various components of a Visualforce page (such as the ones listed above) without having to modify its code?
2. Is it possible to restrict the number of records that can be created for a custom metadata type to one? There is no need for more than one metadata record in this case.
3. There is no **Rich Text** field type for custom metadata. How then could I give admins the ability to specify rich text for the Visualforce page if I use a custom metadata type?
4. Would building a **Visualforce tab** or a **Lightning app page + a LWC** for this purpose require significantly more effort than simply setting up a custom metadata type?

Thanks

Comment: this reminds me of the config page for designing a Quote in CPQ (they used a custom object in lieu of custom metadata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you're talking about admin-specified rich text, and the admins are trusted (that is, you're not worried about an admin injecting malicious markup; I'd warn, say, an ISV against using this because they don't know what various customer admins might do), you could allow them to enter markup directly in a long text area in the custom metadata record and render it with escape="false".

Doesn't give you RTA input features, but it does allow for formatting.

Comment: Thanks Avrom, that's a good suggestion. We ended up going with Custom Metadata without allowing markup due to security considerations.